# How to prevent code duplication for CodeIgniter form validation?

Tags: codeigniter, validation, dry

This is sample of function in the Staff controller for this question

```
function newStaff()
{
    $data = array();

    $data['departmentList'] = $this->department_model->list_department();
    $data['branchList'] = $this->branch_model->list_branch();
    $data['companyList'] = $this->company_model->list_company();

    $this->load->view('staff/newstaff', $data);

}

function add_newStaff()
{
    //when user submit the form, it will call this function
    //if form validation false

    if ($this->validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['departmentList'] = $this->department_model->list_department();
        $data['branchList'] = $this->branch_model->list_branch();
        $data['companyList'] = $this->company_model->list_company();

        $this->load->view('staff/newstaff', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        //submit data into DB
    }

}
```

From the function add_newStaff(), i need to load back all the data from database if the form validation return false. This can be troublesome since I need to maintain two copy of codes. Any tips that I can use to prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats preventing you from doing the following

```
  function newStaff()
    {
        $data = $this->_getData();

        $this->load->view('staff/newstaff', $data);

    }

    function add_newStaff()
    {
        //when user submit the form, it will call this function
        //if form validation false

        if ($this->validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data = $this->_getData();

            $this->load->view('staff/newstaff', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            //submit data into DB
        }

    }

    private function _getData()
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['departmentList'] = $this->department_model->list_department();
        $data['branchList'] = $this->branch_model->list_branch();
        $data['companyList'] = $this->company_model->list_company();

        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you change the action your form submits to so that it points to the same service you use for the initial form request with something like the following.  This would also mean that you'd have the POST values retained between page-loads if you wanted to retain any of the submitted values in your form.

```
function newStaff()
{
    // validation rules

    if ($this->validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        //submit data into DB
    }
    else
    {
         $data = array();
         $data['departmentList'] = $this->department_model->list_department();
         $data['branchList'] = $this->branch_model->list_branch();
         $data['companyList'] = $this->company_model->list_company();

         $this->load->view('staff/newstaff', $data);
    }
}
```